# "int is too big to convert" error when trying to plot in python/matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

As far as I can tell this question does not have an answer on this site.

I'm trying to plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hexbin(ds['sale_date'], ds['sale_price'])
plt.show()
```

where `ds['sale_date'].head()` gives:

```
0   2016-08-01
1   2016-05-01
2   2017-07-01
3   2015-03-01
4   2017-02-01
Name: sale_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The plot returns an error:

```
~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
    346 
    347     dt = (np.datetime64(get_epoch()) +
--> 348           np.timedelta64(int(np.round(x * MUSECONDS_PER_DAY)), 'us'))
    349     if dt < np.datetime64('0001-01-01') or dt >= np.datetime64('10000-01-01'):
    350         raise ValueError(f'Date ordinal {x} converts to {dt} (using '

OverflowError: int too big to convert
```

The dates are from 2010 to 2020. I am having trouble understanding the error, since this seems like this should work out of the box.

Comment: did you find an answer for this question?